# iOS performance difference between big-dimension png image vs big-filesize png image

Tags: performance, image, ios, memory

My storybook app has a mountainBackground.png.
On top will be some animals that have small animations.
The animals in its png will be surrounded by transparency so I can overlay it cleanly on top of the mountain.

To save myself time and headache, I would prefer to dump my animal pictures from Adobe Illustrator with the same dimensions as my mountainBackground.png (like giraffe1.png and lion1.png) instead of doing a "wrapped" dimension (like giraffe2.png and lion2.png)

The file size between full and wrapped images are not that big.
I don't particularly care too much about 70kb vs 30kb.

The question is..
Will iPad/iPhone/iPod have performance problems (speed, processing, memory etc) when displaying big (in dimensions, not in size) multiple pictures?
How about 10 animals? So 10 animals that are 2048 x 2048 dimensions but small in file size.
How about 10 animals with some small animations (moving, panning, zooming, stretching, flipping images, etc).

[full vs wrapped](http://img820.imageshack.us/img820/716/fullvswrap.png)

Please click link for pictures. Unfortunately, I cant post images yet.

Comment: I would recommend replacing one of your tags with ios. Probably size or dimension.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, unfortunately.

A rendered image will take up something like pixel_width * pixel_height * 4 bytes of memory no matter their contents, since they are uncompressed when used on the screen.

There is also a limit (or at least Apple used to warn about) using images larger than 1024 x 1024.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was using 2048 x 2048 so when I zoom in, the picture quality wouldn't look pixelated.

Comment: The issue is not pixelation, the issue is that large (dimension-wise) images uses up lots of RAM memory.